# Algorithm to detect equivalent expressions

Tags: algorithm, expression

For fun I am playing around with a program to solve the [24 game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_Game), and I'm trying to find a way to avoid displaying equivalent expressions when checking for multiple solutions.

For example, given the numbers `6, 6, 6, 6`, the algorithm may (iteratively or recursively) generate several equivalent expressions.
For example: `((6 + 6) + 6) + 6`, `(6 + 6) + (6 + 6)` and others, since all of them mean "add the four sixes together".

Obviously, things become more interesting when dealing with all four arithmetic operands.
For example, the expressions `A * B + C * D` and `C * D + B * A` are also equivalent.

Another case, which may be more difficult to detect is `A - B - C - D` vs `A - (C + B + D)`

Ideas that I have so far:

1. Only using parentheses when needed (by tracking precedence and associativity).
2. Ordering operands for easy comparisons.

Comment: Do you mean your algorithm may work at the same time with infix, postfix or polish notation?

Comment: No, I mean figure out whether two arithmetic expressions are equivalent, and I don't care what notation it works with

Answer (score 1):

After you generated all the possible expressions that result in 24, I would add a normalization step. The goal of this step is to remove redundant parenthesis.

A nice explanation of how to [remove redundant parenthesis is given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403396/1090562). After that you just have a set of all your normalized expressions.

Comment: This is a start, but you need more normalisation -- e.g. presumably you want to consider `2 + 4 + 9 + 9` to be the same as `4 + 9 + 2 + 9` and so on.  You can do this by picking an order for all operands to associative and commutative operators like `+` and `*` (e.g. smallest first).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, you are right. Thank you, I forgot about that. And yes, it can be solved by sorting operands inside of a group of commutative operators. You also forgot about minus. `(a -b -c)`. Minus can be treated like +: `a + (-b) + (-c)` and sorting -b and -c.