# Store Math formula

Tags: java, math, formula

I'm working on an application that gives the user a hand to create mathematical formulas with variables and that could use them afterwards.

Example of a mathematical formula that the user can create:

```
 A*B+ (C/D*E)
```

After creating the formula, the user can use it in calculations, so I should parse it and retrieve the different variables (in our example:"A, B, C, D and E") and create a form for entering the values of these variables.

My question is: How do I store my formula?

I thought of a String that I would parse manually to retrieve the variables, and use Maths.eval to calculate the formula. 
Or else, I could store my formula in JSON to facilitate the recuperation of variables after.

What do you think is the right way to do it?

Thank you

NB : I know my question may be misspelled, I apologize.

Comment: Is there a specific issue with doing it either of those ways?

Comment: No, I was just wondering if there wasn't a cleaner way to do it that could be easily maintained.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to represent, parse and evaluate such formulas is to use [Binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree). This is especially useful when having to deal with operator priorities (* before +), brackets, etc. Moreover, tree traversal is a natural approach to solving such problems and different traversal types can be used (inorder, preorder, ...).

*EDIT:* The evaluation can be [implemented via stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136153/build-binary-expression-tree).

Comment: I agree, that is what should be done normally. But in my case, the formulas are relatively simple, and for the calculation I will use the ScriptEngine JavaScript:

ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

I was wondering about the persistence of the formula, finally, I'm going to store it in a String that I'll parse later.

Comment: Well, if the input to your evaluator is a String, then I don't see any reason why not to store it as a String :) I have no experience with ScriptEngine, but if you will be evaluating with JavaScript, you can simply store the formula as a string as it is (with the variables) and then prepend it with variable assignment, such as `var A = 10; var B = 20; eval("A+B");`.